# Is there a way to call a Web Service with Client and Service Certificates in powershell?

Tags: powershell, web-services, certificate, servicepointmanager, new-webserviceproxy

I'm working on a Powershell script, that needs to call a web service, with a Client and Service Certificate.
I have the connect semi-working in C# .Net.
In .Net app.config i have these configurations:

```
...
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="false" establishSecurityContext="false"/>
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CertificateAuthenticationBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="Capital Market FIONAsi" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
            <serviceCertificate>
              <defaultCertificate findValue="example.dk" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
```

The .net code.

```
var stinaProxy = new StinaServiceProxy("StinaService");
var stinaHandshakeResponse = stinaProxy.HandShake(testValueArgument);
```

This seems to get me passed certificate validation in .net

But as mentioned, I actually need this to work for me in powershell.
I don't know how to call a webservice and suppy both the client and the service certificate.

Here is what I got so far in powershell, but it ends in timeout, witch I believe is a certificate problem.

```
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

    $ClientCertificate = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My\af4269b1d7190be23f1e48001fc345011f7ade80
    $defaultCertificate = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My\42097f29a5bd2fb4d9960e74f67654d369b7a2e3
    $url = "https://example.dk/StinaService.svc?wsdl"
    $webserviceex = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $url -Namespace WebServiceProxy 
    $webserviceex.Timeout = 5000
    $webserviceex.ClientCertificates.Add($ClientCertificate)
    $webserviceex.ClientCertificates.Add($defaultCertificate)
    $handshakeResult = $webserviceex.HandShake("1234!")
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: What do you mean by service certificate? It looks like you're doing the client certificate authentication correctly, but I'm not sure what `$defaultCertificate` is supposed to be used for. Do you have any access to the webservice to see why it doesn't respond? Normally a bad/missing certificate should return a 403.

Comment: I guess your client is checking the Service Certificate for validity and failing or timing out at revocation list checks. I don't think you need to add the `$defaultcertificate` to the `ClientCertficates` collection, you just need to trust the Service certificate. Have you tried adding the `PeerTrust` attribute to your `$webservicex` [proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.security.x509servicecertificateauthentication.certificatevalidationmode?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your inputs.
Cpt.Whale, I think I need two certificates, but I'm not good at this certificate stuff. I don't have access to the webservice backend / logs. 

RichMoss, Actually I didn't believe that adding it to the ClientCertificates collection was the trick, just an attempt from my side. I have added the certificate to the machines store. 
I don't see the possibility to add the PeerTrust anywere in powershell. Do you know how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the `ServiceCertificate` is going to be the cause of your issues since only the client should care. Have you tried setting your `$webserviceex` with *only* the `$ClientCertificate` added? Usually, you would only add additional certificates if you had a chain and needed CA certificates too.

---

I did find how to add service certificates in powershell. You didn't include the classes you used, but I was able to use `[System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost]` to create something similar to what you have.  here is a powershell example of a webservice using client and server certificates.

```
[URI]$URI = 'https://example.dk/StinaService.svc'

# WSHttpBinding
$binding = New-Object System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding
$binding.Security.Mode = [System.ServiceModel.SecurityMode]::TransportWithMessageCredential
$binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = [System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType]::Certificate
$binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType   = [System.ServiceModel.MessageCredentialType]::Certificate

# Create service host
$ServiceHost = [System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost]::new([StinaService], $URI)
    $ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint([IStinaService], $binding,"")

    # Add Service Certificate (authenticate the server)
    $ServiceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(
        [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation]::LocalMachine,
        [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName]::My,
        [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType]::FindBySubjectName,
        'example.dk'
    )
    # Add Client Certificate (authenticate the client)
    $ServiceHost.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
        [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation]::LocalMachine,
        [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName]::My,
        [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType]::FindBySubjectName,
        'Capital Market FIONAsi' 
    )

# Open the service
$ServiceHost.Open()

# Close the service.
$ServiceHost.Close()
```

I based this off of the example .net WCF code [in this MS how-to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/message-security-with-a-certificate-client), and defined the `[StinaService]` ServiceContract using the definitions from Chrissy Lemaire in her [powershell tcp service proof-of-concept](https://blog.netnerds.net/2015/03/creating-a-wcf-net-tcp-service-and-client-using-powershell/).

---

Note that you can probably ignore this example - just copy your existing .Net code, format it to powershell like this, and import the same app.config you are already using.

```
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", "$dllPath.config")
$null = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($dllPath)
```

Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/33927024/7411885.

Comment: Thank you Cpt. Whale
It seems like the right approach on your powershell example. 
I had to add this line first: Add-Type -AssemblyName System.ServiceModel
But the script then fails to run this line:
$ServiceHost = [System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost]::new([StinaService], $URI)

Unable to find type [StinaService].

Comment: @SimonBruun Sorry, I'm not very familiar with the actual service definition and binding steps. `AddServiceEndpoint()` might not be what you need if you're using a wsdl.